# How to add a key in the browser's 'Local Storage' using robot framework?

Tags: authentication, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, session-cookies

I was able to set a Cookie
But When I checked login mechanism, I found that I should be setting key in the 'Local Storage'

Below is code for same:

```
Successful Login
   Create Session    loginsession  url=${base_url}     verify=true
   ${data}     Create dictionary   grant_type=password     username=${username}  password=${password}
   ${headers}  Create Dictionary     Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded     authorization=${authorization}
   ${resp}     POST On Session    loginsession     /oauth/token  params=${data}  headers=${headers}

   ${access_token}      Get Value From Json    ${resp.json()}      $.access_token
   Launch browser and maximize it   ${browser}
   Add Cookie   token   ${resp.json()}  domain=qa.mycrm.com
   Agent lands on My CRM Login Page
   Go To  https://qa.mycrm.com/dashboard/
```

I am seeking help on how can i set a key in browser's Local Storage

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try importing Seleniumlibrary and use Execute Javascript?

> Execute Javascript window.localStorage.setItem("abc", "SaHlOcAhIeBmy")

Comment: Yes I tried after your suggestion and it worked BUT the only issue I am right now facing is that response that I am setting as 'token'  is encapsulated within square braces i.e [] and this is which I don't want

Successful Login
   --- some robot code --
   Execute Javascript 
   window.localStorage.setItem("token",JSON.stringify(${jsonResponse}))
   Agent lands on CRM Login Page

Comment: Exact code that will solve this issue

'Successful Login

 //.. code to post login api and fetch response 

   Launch browser and maximize it   ${browser}
   ${a}     Execute Javascript      return JSON.stringify(${resp.json()});
   Execute Javascript   window.localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(${a}))
   Go To  https://qa.mycrm.com/dashboard'


So extra square braces were coming in the response was due to use of this line
${jsonResponse}      Get Value From Json    ${resp.json()}      $